# Why can't I scan the user's input?

Tags: java

It wouldn't let the user input a string. It runs the parts that isn't bold, but it stops running when I declare the String variable "operation". I was thinking it would let the user input "p" or "c". But it wouldn't let the user input anything. It just says "build successful".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] items = {"notepad","pen","pencil","eraser","marker"};
    int[] quantity = new int[5];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input the quantity for notepad, pen, pencil, eraser, and marker. Enter them in the correct order.");
    quantity[0] = input.nextInt();
    quantity[1] = input.nextInt();
    quantity[2] = input.nextInt();
    quantity[3] = input.nextInt();
    quantity[4] = input.nextInt();
    while (quantity[0]<0||quantity[1]<0||quantity[2]<0||quantity[3]<0||quantity[4]<0){//loop if user enters invalid number
            System.out.println("Invalid input, enter numbers greater than or equal to 0.");
            quantity[0] = input.nextInt();
            quantity[1] = input.nextInt();
            quantity[2] = input.nextInt();
            quantity[3] = input.nextInt();
            quantity[4] = input.nextInt();
            if (quantity[0]>=0&&quantity[1]>=0&&quantity[2]>=0&&quantity[3]>=0&&quantity[4]>=0)
                break;//breaks out the loop            
}
    double[] price = {0,0,0,0,0};
    System.out.println("Please enter the price for the notepad, pen, pencil, eraser,and marker. Enter them in the correct order.");
    price[0] = input.nextDouble();
    price[1] = input.nextDouble();
    price[2] = input.nextDouble();
    price[3] = input.nextDouble();
    price[4] = input.nextDouble();
     while (price[0]<0||price[1]<0||price[2]<0||price[3]<0||price[4]<0){//loop if user enters invalid number
            System.out.println("Invalid input, enter numbers greater than or equal to 0.");
            price[0] = input.nextDouble();
            price[1] = input.nextDouble();
            price[2] = input.nextDouble();
            price[3] = input.nextDouble();
            price[4] = input.nextDouble();
     }
            if (price[0]>=0&&price[1]>=0&&price[2]>=0&&price[3]>=0&&price[4]>=0){

    System.out.println("After you input the quantity and the price, there are a few options for you to choose to operate from:");
    System.out.println("Enter p to print inventory, c to check for low inventory, h to display highest and lowest inventory value items, v to display total inventory value, and e to exit the program.");
            }
    **String operation; 
    operation = input.nextLine();
        switch (operation){
            case "p":
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
            case "c":**

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: `nextDouble()` consumes the `double` but leaves a trailing newline.

Comment: So does this affect the fact the the program won't scan the user's input? @ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 0):

you need to flush the buffer between uses of the scanner if you are using it for different data types

input.nextLine();

That should resolve the not taking user input issue

Comment: I don't get how to flush the buffer though..didn't I have input.nextLine(); already? Sorry, I'm kinda new to Java..

Comment: input.nextLine() is different than input.nextInt();
Instead of trying to read something it ensures that that scanner object has no contents (this is useful because some datatypes (string in particular tend to leave a carriage return in the buffer that will cause it to close as soon as the next scanner is requested)

Comment: String operation; 
    operation = input.nextLine();
        switch (operation){
            case "p":
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
            case "c":

Comment: It is the last part that isn't working, the nextInt works fine =o

Comment: Never mind I got it, same thing you mentioned! I'd vote up but I can't because I just made this account. Sorry. =/